# Custom optional parameter in page URL

Tags: permalinks

I'm losing my mind, so I do hope I can get some help here..

What I'm trying to do is to create an optional parameter for search page, just for the sake of SEO

For example, there are the options:

/search/ (category = null)

/search/contracts (category = contracts)

/search/.../ (category = whatever this parameter $1 is)

While search is a page

I've tried adding htaccess rewrite rule, and wordpress simply redirected 301 without passing the parameter. Then I tried with add_rewrite_endpoint, nothing worked whatsoever and I've tried with

```
function wpd_add_query_vars( $qvars ) {
  $qvars[] = 'category';
  return $qvars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpd_add_query_vars' );

add_rewrite_rule(
    '^search/([^/]+)/?',
    'index.php?post_id=806&category=$matches[1]',
    'top'
);

add_rewrite_tag('%category%', '([^&]+)');

flush_rewrite_rules();
```

Do note I tried just about every permutation, also tried plugins, nothing worked. It was either a 404 or the $wp_query->query_vars did not include the parameter.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What is post ID 806? `post_id` isn't a valid query var. `add_rewrite_rule` should also be hooked to run on the `init` action. Rewrite rules have to result in a valid main query, so your best bet is to start with creating a new `WP_Query` that gives you the results you are trying to achieve, then work backwards from that to derive your rule.

Comment: I've tried also with pagename and p, but 806 is page search. I'll try with WP_Query, thanks for the input. But I now I'm seriously doubting going the WP way will take less time than vanilla